# In IndexedDB, is there any scenario where data from a transaction is written to disk but oncomplete does not fire?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

As I understand it, there are two potential outcomes for an IndexedDB transaction:

1. There is some error, so no changes in the transaction are written and oncomplete never fires.
2. Everything works, so the changes are written and then `oncomplete` fires.

But I've heard reports from some users about my application intermittently not working in Chrome, and one of them claims to have debugged it to the point of identifying `oncomplete` as the problem. He says that sometimes `oncomplete` is not firing even though the data is being saved and no error messages are produced.

I understand that this might not be correct because I haven't been able to observe the problem myself and nobody can come up with a set of steps to reproduce it. But I have seen weird browser-specific bugs in IndexedDB before, especially when writing lots of data in multiple transactions to large object stores (which is where the problem occurs). Has anyone noticed something like this?

Comment: I have noticed weird tx when 1) dev console or 2) very long running tx. Without these two, no problem. There are some bugs reported in chromimun relating to these and still not close, i think.

Comment: Do you happen to have links to the Chromium bugs? This is a pretty long running transaction.

Comment: Sorry, i could not find them. Anyways long running tx will NOT be treated nice in browser since they take memory. You will find these problem disappear magically when div console is not in use.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at [**the spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBTransaction-oncomplete) and it says

> To determine if a *transaction* has completed successfully, listen to the transaction’s `complete` *event* rather than the `success` *event* of a particular *request*, because the *transaction* may still fail after the `success` *event* fires.

This is stating there may be cases where a *request* has been successful (i.e. some data may have been written) even though the *transaction* itself has failed (e.g. write interrupted?)

It's still wise to listen for the *complete* event, but you may also want to be listening for *success* on the requests too if this is causing problems, as you can then identify where the error happened on the client's machine and handle the error accordingly, e.g. check how much was written and write more.